# seafile-server error: sqlite3_prepare_v2 failed - disk I/O error (or http error?)

Tags: linux, sqlite

Two days ago my seafile-server (v7.0.5) stopped working, with error logs that look like below. What could be going on - not clear to me if this is an error in the database, in http-server, or in sqlite3_prepare_v2... any advice would be most welcome!

```
[12/11/2019 08:01:54 AM] http-server.c(853): DB error when check repo existence.
[12/11/2019 08:01:55 AM] ../common/seaf-db.c(425): Error prepare statement SELECT 1 FROM Repo WHERE repo_id=?: sqlite3_prepare_v2 failed: disk I/O error.
[12/11/2019 08:01:55 AM] http-server.c(853): DB error when check repo existence.
[12/11/2019 08:01:55 AM] ../common/seaf-db.c(425): Error prepare statement SELECT 1 FROM Repo WHERE repo_id=?: sqlite3_prepare_v2 failed: disk I/O error.
[12/11/2019 08:01:55 AM] http-server.c(853): DB error when check repo existence.
[12/11/2019 08:01:55 AM] ../common/seaf-db.c(425): Error prepare statement SELECT 1 FROM Repo WHERE repo_id=?: sqlite3_prepare_v2 failed: disk I/O error.
[12/11/2019 08:01:55 AM] http-server.c(853): DB error when check repo existence.
[12/11/2019 08:02:07 AM] ../common/seaf-db.c(425): Error prepare statement SELECT repo_id, commit_id FROM Branch WHERE name='master' AND repo_id IN ('5f8cb2cc-78c4-42c2-8e61-45d3e08980f4','16e81793-8d3f-4252-8bb1-2e289f6ca1cb','7c86a0df-d745-4018-be49-325eade14d8a','f7428c97-1934-49b4-9228-17c2302aea30','cd1a0ccd-4650-438d-b090-3884c3bbf536','e80476b5-fc66-4eaf-a63c-5018ff08814b'): sqlite3_prepare_v2 failed: disk I/O error.
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should probably use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question. Also see [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sqlite.

Comment: "disk I/O error" usually means that you need to replace the disk. Any error messages in the server's system log?